# How do I change my screensaver in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: screensaver

I've read the answers to this question for versions of Ubuntu, but it seems many changes were done to this.  A duplicate question has only spaces and no answers.  This should be very simple.  Any ideas please?

Comment: It is very simple and done exactly as it always been. What are you trying to do that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

As I am using 16.04 ubuntu, dont see any option of screen saver. if you really want any screenserver option you will have to download xscreensaver.